# Inbox bold when message unread

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to conditionally style user-to-user messages on my site based on the following:

If the user has not yet accessed the message, it remains bold ("unread").
If the user clicks the link and accesses it, it goes from bold to unbold ("read")

(reference:  this is how many email inboxes work)

Question:  How would I check if the user has clicked on the link to view their new message, or if they have not?  As in, how would I store this information and indicate that it has been "read"?

Comment: `echo $read === true?"<b>":""; echo $message; echo $read === true?"</b>":"";` ?

Comment: Why all the down votes??? I am asking how to check if the user has clicked on the link to view their new message, or if they have not.  How would I store this information and indicate that it has been "read"?  I have updated question to reflect this.

Comment: well that's a better question, add a `read` column in the db, set it to 1  once they have clicked on the link, use that to decide how to format(bold or not) the link

Comment: Ok, perfect, I like that answer :)  If you answer it, I will give you a check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a **read** column in the db (default to 0), set it to 1 once they have clicked on the link, use that to decide how to format(bold or not) the link.

optional it may be worth adding a date field to know when it was first read.

Comment: Thanks.  Since you also seem to know your way around, can you coach me as to why I received so many down votes, even after I reworded the question? (I want to avoid this in the future...)

Answer (score 1):

- in your db, create 1 column 'read'
- create message.php (maybe??)
- the code will update the read column to 1 (as read), so default value for read is 0

hope this helps :)